# Reductions to and from PRIME

Tags: reductions

I think PRIME (is the given number a prime number?) is a good example a decision problem.  Therefore, when I'm trying to explain reduction, I'd like to give an example of a problem that is related to PRIME.

What are decision problems that can be reduced to PRIME, and how do these reductions look like?

What are decision problems that PRIME can reduce to, and how do these reductions look like?

Comment: After I read your comment, I realized that question need to be edited. What I really want to know is the reduction, not the problem.  There are lots of example of reduction for NP complete problem.  But I cannot find reduction to or from `PRIME`

Comment: Are you interested in any particular notion of reduction?

Comment: I'd like to see how to reduce a specific poly time decision problem to or from `PRIME`.  I see a lot of reduction example in NP complete proof.  But I think `PRIME` is an easy to understand.  So I would like to see it in a reduction example.

Comment: PRIME is not very suitable to reductions, unfortunately.

Comment: @YuvalFilmus I like `PRIME` because it is easy to be explained in term of language L = {10, 11, 101, 111, 1011, ...}  Are there any other problem that can be easily explained in term of language and is more suitable to reduction?

Comment: You might like the problem described in [this answer](https://mathoverflow.net/a/72633/7732), in which an instance consists of three natural numbers. A simple problem which is actually about strings (an instance is a single string!) is described in [this paper](https://www.math.ucsd.edu/~sbuss/ResearchWeb/Shuffle/shuffle.pdf).

Comment: @YuvalFilmus Thank you very much for the links.  I like the Square problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you're talking about polynomial-time reductions, since PRIME is in $P$, you can reduce it to any non-trivial decision problem (for which there is at least one instance with answer YES and at least one instance with answer NO). Moreover, any problem in $P$ can be reduced to PRIME.

To reduce an instance $I$ of PRIME to an instance $I_Q$ of non trivial decision problem $Q$, let $Y_Q$ and $N_Q$ be a YES and a NO instance for $Q$, respectively. The reduction is as follows: solve $I$ using a [polynomial-time algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primality_test#Fast_deterministic_tests) for PRIME. Then, let

$$I_Q = \begin{cases}Y_Q & \mbox{if $I$ is a YES instance}, \\ N_Q & \mbox{if $I$ is a NO instance}.\end{cases}$$

To reduce an instance $I_Q$ of a problem $Q \in P$ to an instance $I$ of PRIME, solve $I_Q$ using a polynomial-time algorithm for $Q$ and define

$$I = \begin{cases}2 & \mbox{if $I_Q$ is a YES instance}, \\ 1 & \mbox{if $I_Q$ is a NO instance.}\end{cases}$$

Comment: I have a question.  For the second part, does to reduce Q <= PRIME means to solve Q using PRIME algorithm?

Comment: Assuming we are talking about Karp reductions, it implies that you can solve an instance of $Q$ in polynomial time by using an algorithm for `PRIME`. The converse direction is not true (that would be: "if you can solve $Q$ in polynomial time using an algorithm for `PRIME` then $Q$ is Karp-reducible to `PRIME`"). A Karp reduction also maps YES instances of $Q$ to YES instances of `PRIME` and NO instances of $Q$ to NO instances of `PRIME`.

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer.